# NSFetchedResultsController not updating when using performBlock:

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a `NSManagedObjectContext`, `moc`, with a concurrency type of `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`. `moc` is also associated with a `NSFetchedResultsController`. The `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods are implemented properly.

When executing the following code on the **main thread**, my `NSFetchedResultsController` doesn't refresh (delegate method not called)

```
[moc performBlock:^{
  ...
  [moc save:&error]; 
}];
```

When using the following, the `NSFetchedResultsController`'s delegate methods are properly called:

```
[moc performBlockAndWait:^{
  ...
  [moc save:&error]; 
}];
```

(it also refreshes without calling `performBlockAndWait:` and executing the code without a block.).

Why is that?

*Note: I know I don't necessarily have to call performBlock/performBlockAndWait because I'm already on the main thread, but I never know if this might change in the future.*

Comment: do you realize `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods?

Comment: yes. When I'm saying that the NSFetchedResultsController doesn't refresh, I mean the delegate methods are not called properly. Will update my question.

Comment: ok, do you handle `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`?

Comment: `performBlock:` only queue your code for execution and it does not run immediately. wait for it to execute then test your changes.

Comment: The delegate method should still be called, but it might not happen immediately. How long did you wait for the method to be called? It should be "very soon" but it won't be immediate.

Comment: @ValentinShamardin I don't have to, this is the same context as the NSFetchedResultsController's context.